# Running CUDA on ThinkPad w550s Ubuntu system (Quadro K620M)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cuda

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 and I am new to GPU. I installed CUDA 7.5, the nvidia driver on my computer is

```
$ nvidia-settings -q NvidiaDriverVersion
Attribute 'NvidiaDriverVersion' (xxx-ThinkPad-W550s:0.0): 340.96
Attribute 'NvidiaDriverVersion' (xxx-ThinkPad-W550s:0[gpu:0]): 340.96
```

When I go to `/usr/local/cuda/samples/1_Utilities/deviceQuery` and execute `./deviceQuery` it will show me that

> CUDA driver version is insufficient for CUDA runtime version

I was trying to update and reinstall the new driver 352 by using `sudo apt-get install nvidia-352 nvidia-settings`. But when I check the driver version, it is still `340.96`.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Did you reboot after upgrading the driver?

Comment: Er..., that worked for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you upgrade the NVIDIA kernel driver, you must reboot the machine before the new driver can become active. That was the problem in the case.